# Удаление дубликатов из разных таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы, А и B. В обеих разное количество колонок и их названий. Надо удалить из таблицы А полностью строку, если ее колонка aaa содержит совпадение с колонкой bbb в таблице В.

не срабатывает:

```
DELETE A FROM A JOIN B WHERE A.aaa=B.bbb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта.

Первый это использовать `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM A a
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM B b
   WHERE b.bbb = a.aaa
);
```

Второй - это `IN` с подзапросом:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE aaa IN (
   SELECT bbb
   FROM B
);
```